# Registry scoping for NPM packages that are not scoped on the target registry

Tags: node.js, npm

I am looking to use multiple registries in a project. I need to target multiple registries, which lead me to scoping. I would like to access **package-a** from **registry-a** and **package-b** from **registry-b** among numerous other packages that come from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com) (default registry). In *.npmrc*,

```
@first=registry=https://registry-a.org/registry/
@second=registry=https://registry-b.org/registry/
registry=https://www.npmjs.com
```

When attempting to run
`npm install @first/package-a` it results in an error. When analyzing this I can see that the URL itself has the scope before the package name. The result looks like:

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry-a.org/registry/@first%2fpackage-a - Not found
```

Neither of these packages have been published with the scope. Is there a way around this?